# How can I log to two different files in Log4perl?

Tags: perl, log4perl

I have a Perl script that produces two different streams of data.

I need to log them to two separate log files.

I'm aware of 2 approaches that result in different log files but neither one seems helpful in my situation:

1. Using categories (which are Perl module names).

   In my case, the streams are both produced in the same code ("main" package, but that's irrelevant, what matters is that literally I have lines of code next to each other logging to 2 locations that can't be separated into different Perl modules).
2. Using different loglevels.

   However, both should log with the same priority (e.g. both are logging `info()` calls and `error()` as appropriate) so I can't use the FAQ recipe for [logging WARN/ERROR to different files](http://log4perl.sourceforge.net/releases/Log-Log4perl/docs/html/Log/Log4perl/FAQ.html#c7fa8).

Comment: Additionally, the messages don't have specific patterns, so using custom filters with a regex wouldn't work as far as I can see.

Answer (score 5):

[Categories](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl#Categories) in Log4perl are arbitrary and aren't related to the class hierarchy of your application.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Log::Log4perl qw(get_logger);

my $conf = q(
log4perl.category.first  = DEBUG, FileAppender1
log4perl.category.second = DEBUG, FileAppender2

log4perl.appender.FileAppender1          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.FileAppender1.filename = first.log
log4perl.appender.FileAppender1.layout   = Log::Log4perl::Layout::SimpleLayout

log4perl.appender.FileAppender2          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.FileAppender2.filename = second.log
log4perl.appender.FileAppender2.layout   = Log::Log4perl::Layout::SimpleLayout
);

Log::Log4perl::init(\$conf);

my $logger1 = get_logger('first');
my $logger2 = get_logger('second');

$logger1->debug('foo');
$logger2->info('bar');
$logger1->error('baz');
```

first.log

```
DEBUG - foo
ERROR - baz
```

second.log

```
INFO - bar
```